How to connect to Personal Sharepoint by Power Automate?
I want to create a flow in Power Automate that once a month copy all the files from the folder to the new location to create some kind of archive.
Unfortunately, I am not able to connect to personal sharepoint through Power Automate. When I am using custom value in Site Adress, Power Automate still can't find any folders or lists in this adress. Is it possible to connect PA to Personal Sharepoint? Should I do this in other way?
Example link: https://organization-my.sharepoint.com/personal/organization_my_name_pl
Error

You could use List files in folder action, and make sure you have the correct connection.


Your personal SharePoint is, in fact, OneDrive. So you can use the OneDrive for Business connector.
With the List files in folder action you can get your files to copy them to another location. Add For each, a Get file content action on each file and, finally, a Create file to create the same file in another location, like a SharePoint site.

